# Protractor .npm-global Error: more than one config file specified

Tags: protractor

Tried everything suggested online. But still getting the error.

protractor --version
Version 5.4.2

npm -version
6.1.0

```
protractor Testfiles/Conf.js —-suite cti

Error: Error: more than one config file specified
at /Users/m/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js:166:15
at /Users/m/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/index.js:307:21
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at parseArgs (/Users/m/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/index.js:305:16)
```

Comment: Hi, post your config file to make it easier to understand , but anyway, silly question.. are you accessing the correct folder to trigger the execution?

Comment: @Alexandre thank you for looking. I removed node, nvm protractor etc. Reinstalled and not having this issue anymore